# Why are there two database tables to handle taxonomy terms structure

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

There is a `taxonomy_term_data` table and there is a `taxonomy_term_hierarchy` table.  Why are there 2 tables, instead of them being combined?

taxonomy_term_hierachy strucutre

- description of table: Stores the hierarchical relationship between
- field: tid: 'Primary Key: the taxonomy_term_data.tid of the term'
- field: parent: 'Primary Key: The taxonomy_term_data.tid of the term's parent.
  0 indicates no parent.'

taxonomy_term_data structure:

- description of table: Stores term information.
- fields: vid, name, description, format, weight

**Question motivation**
I am the maintainer of the draggableviews module.  Currently module is using just 1 table.  Going forward, the module's goal is to mimic taxonomy structure.  Tried to search the web for an answer but could not find one.

Comment: A term can have multiple parents. This is easier represented in the taxonomy_term_hierachy strucutre

Comment: @Reynolds, that would make sense, but tid is unqiue (primary key) and the parent field is an integer.  Can you explain this?

Comment: @iStryker Not quite - it's a compound key across tid + parent, not just on tid

Comment: My mistake, I did not see the compound key, thought it was just on tid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`taxonomy_term_data` is the base table for the taxonomy entity type. It holds ID, property and bundle data for that entity type.

`taxonomy_term_hierarchy` holds the parent/child relationship between taxonomy terms (which of course can be multiple in nature).

You can't store the data for anything more than a one-to-one relationship in the same table, hence the split into two.